# Safari 6.1 HTML5 Video Flicker When Behind Content

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, html5-video

Here's the scoop. I have a video that is playing behind the navigation bar and logo of a page. It works great in all browsers except Safari 6.1. Unfortunately 6.1 needs to be supported. The issue with 6.1 is that the content that is on top of the video will flicker like crazy while the video is playing. It seems to be browser related. I've tried backface-visibility and transforms, but neither seem to work. There may be nothing that will fix it. Has anyone been able to find a solution or does anyone have any insight into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

*If* Safari 6.1 supports drawing from a video onto a canvas (I think it should), then you can try drawing each frame onto a canvas, then drawing the overlay material. You might have to implement double buffering yourself, i.e., draw video frame onto an off-screen canvas, draw overlay, then copy off-screen canvas to on-screen canvas.

Unfortunately this doesn't let you put HTML elements in front of the video. You'd also have to implement whatever interactivity you want from the nav bar on the canvas.

Or you COULD try just copying each video frame to the canvas, and having other HTML in front of the canvas, and see if that works. But if putting HTML in front of the video causes flicker, then I would expect that HTML in front of a canvas probably does too.